# Geopandas/folium map not displaying?

Tags: geojson, geopandas

I'm trying to use a combination of geopandas, pandas and folium to create a polygon map that I can embed  incorporate into a web page.

For some reason, it's not displaying and wonder if anyone can help.

The steps I've taken:

1. Grabbed a .shp from the UK's OS for Parliamentary boundaries.
2. I've then used geopandas to change the projection to epsg=4326 and then exported as GeoJSON which takes the following format:

   { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PCON13CD": "E14000532", "PCON13CDO": "A03", "PCON13NM": "Altrincham and Sale West" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.313999519326579, 53.357408280545918 ], [ -2.313941776174758, 53.358341455420039 ], [ -2.31519699483377, 53.359035664493433 ], [ -2.317953152796459, 53.359102954309151 ], [ -2.319855973429864, 53.358581917200119 ],... ] ] ] } },...

Then what I'd like to do is mesh this with a dataframe of constituencies in the following format, dty:

```
constituency        count
0   Burton          667
1   Cannock Chase   595
2   Cheltenham      22
3   Cheshire East   2
4   Congleton       1
5   Derbyshire Dales    1
6   East Staffordshire  4

import folium
mapf = folium.Map(width=700, height=370, tiles = "Stamen Toner", zoom_start=8, location=     ["53.0219392","-2.1597434"])


mapf.geo_json(geo_path="geo_json_shape2.json", 
              data_out="data.json", 
              data=dty, 
              columns=["constituency","count"], 
              key_on="feature.properties.PCON13NM.geometry.type.Polygon",
              fill_color='PuRd',
              fill_opacity=0.7, 
              line_opacity=0.2, 
              reset="True")
```

The output from mapf looks like:

mapf.json_data

```
{'../../Crime_data/staffs_data92.json': [{'Burton': 667,
   'Cannock Chase': 595,
   'Cheltenham': 22,
   'Cheshire East': 2,
   'Congleton': 1,
   'Derbyshire Dales': 1,
   'East Staffordshire': 4,
   'Lichfield': 438,
   'Newcastle-under-Lyme': 543,
   'North Warwickshire': 1,
   'Shropshire': 17,
   'South Staffordshire': 358,
   'Stafford': 623,
   'Staffordshire Moorlands': 359,
   'Stoke-on-Trent Central': 1053,
   'Stoke-on-Trent North': 921,
   'Stoke-on-Trent South': 766,
   'Stone': 270,
   'Tamworth': 600,
   'Walsall': 1}]}
```

Although the mapf.create_map() function successfully creates a map, the polygons don't render.

Can anyone suggest any debugging steps?

I'm never clear on how to add the full data files if anyone needs them, so please let me know.

Here's the input json file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hbfwb95864uiru/geo_json_shape2.json?dl=0

Here's the output data.json:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9wh2bodr8feqo9/staffs_data89.json?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide both geo_json_shape2.json and data.json files, please? More easy to help

Comment: I've now added those links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some debugging on client side, your issue is that you define `key_on="feature.properties.PCON13NM.geometry.type.Polygon",` whereas it should `be key_on="feature.properties.PCON13NM",`

Another big issue is the fact that your geometries are too big whereas you only need some geometries to display. Just for info, your GeoJSON is "only" 20Mb (your browser will go down)

The best choice would be to filter features **before** you make the transformation to GeoJSON.

Some tests below using GDAL

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" filtered.geojson -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT * FROM OGRGeoJSON WHERE PCON13NM IN ('Derbyshire Dales', 'Cheltenham', 'Cannock Chase', 'Congleton', 'Cheshire East', 'Burton', 'East Staffordshire')" geo_json_shape2.json
```

With this, the GeoJSON file on my side is 140K. You can also simplify it with [Mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org) if required.

See below image for an overview of the result
[image: Folium result demo]