# How to make polygons clickable in Leaflet.js / folium

Tags: python, leaflet, pandas

I'm trying to create a clickable leaflet.js map using folium and Python.

After a previous query - answered here [Geopandas/folium map not displaying](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120361/geopandas-folium-map-not-displaying) - I've added the polygons.

But I'm getting a little bit lost in the documentation on what to add to the output javascript to create a pop up for each polygon using the dataframe.

Can anyone give me a steer in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't have time to take a look before but following Leaflet documentation
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson, you just have to change GeoJSON layer declaration from:

```
gJson_layer_1 = L.geoJson(gjson_1, {style: style_1}).addTo(map)
```

to :

```
gJson_layer_1 = L.geoJson(gjson_1, {
  style: style_1,
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.PCON13NM);
  }
}).addTo(map)
```

Comment: Really appreciate your time. I took one look at the Javascript in the docs and was completely lost.